# How to use UserCreationForm in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have followed [this](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/extending-djangos-user-model-with-onetoonefield) tutorial to test out the User authentication and Signals in Django. I don't know what I should do with this part (found from the [first](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/building-a-user-registration-form-with-djangos-built-in-authentication) post of this tutorial):

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    birthdate = forms.DateField()
    discord_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Discord ID')
    zoom_id = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Zoom ID')
    text = forms.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "password1", "password2", "birthdate", "email", "discord_id", "zoom_id"]
```

With those imports I get an error `NameError: name 'forms' is not defined` and if I add an import `from django import forms` I get errors like `AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'TextField'`.

Sohuld I add all the fields from my Model into this `RegisterForm` -class I want to include to the registration process? What do I do to the fields that are textFields in my Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `forms.TextField` which does not exist in Django, you need to use `forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use `CharField` instead of `TextField`. Django uses `CharField` in its forms with default widget as `TextArea`.

You can find more details here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#charfield

Comment: In my Model, I have both, CharFields and TextFields. what I try to ask is if it's a TextField in database, what should I use in my forms.py if TextFields are not allowed in forms?

Comment: You can just create a model form for models